# Diretório recursivo PHP

Tags: php, html, css, aplicação-web, diretório

Preciso incluir um arquivo de um diretório recursivo, estou utilizando a seguinte forma:

```
<?php 
  require_once '../../cabecalho.php';
?>
```

Ok, o que está acontecendo é o seguinte. O cabeçalho, que seria o header da página + menu está carregando, porém, somente o HTML, tudo que está referenciado dentro do header, como por exemplo:

```
<link href="css/materialize.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection"/>
```

não está carregando, ajuda?

Comment: olhando assim, parece que o caminho do seu css que não esta sendo localizado.

Comment: O que é exatamente um "diretório recursivo"? Pesquisei agora em dois _search engines_, e só apareceu a sua pergunta com o termo exato.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para funcionar dessa forma, o caminho do css, javascript ou imagem devem ser relativos a página que está incluindo o cabeçalho e não do cabeçalho em si.

Ou como alternativa, você pode usar o caminho absoluto para incluir os arquivos, por exemplo:

```
<link href="http://seuservidor.com/css/materialize.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection"/>
```

Comment: Com base na raíz é até mais prático: `/css/materialize.css`

Comment: Exatamente. Coloquei daquela forma porque existe alguns servidores locais tipo localhost/webdav/projeto, etc.. que pode dar erro. Mas para usar online é a melhor opção